# Change PasswordBox PlaceHolder Text Foreground color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties, passwordbox

I have a PasswordBox

```xml
<PasswordBox 
    MaxLength="12" 
    PlaceholderText="Password" 
    Foreground="Black" 
    Background="#eeeeee"/>
```

And I want to change the `PlaceholderForeground` color like I would on a regular `TextBox` but there is no property like that and after searching through the internet I found no solution that A worked for me B I understood, all the xaml code was too lengthy with style and resources of 50 lines all for such a simple property change I don't know why WPF has to be so overly complicated for no reason

Can anybody sugguest a solution that is possibly not 50 lines of xaml code that simply changes the foreground color of the placeholder text in the PasswordBox.

Comment: The WPF [`PasswordBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.passwordbox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#properties) does not have such a property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't change the placeholder color without creating something custom.** But there are workarounds without huge snippets of XAML markup.

The easiest way that came to my mind is creating a custom control that derives from `PasswordBox`. You'll only have to override `OnRender`:

1. Call `base.OnRender`
2. Check that there's no text in the password box, and it isn't focused
3. Create a `FormattedText` object, maybe like this:

```cs
var placeholder = new FormattedText(
  PlaceholderText,
  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
  FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
  new Typeface(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, FontStretch),
  FontSize,
  new SolidColorBrush(Color.Blue),  // Or whatever you want
  VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).PixelsPerDip);
```

4. Draw it at the top-left corner of the content:

```cs
drawingContext.DrawText(placeholder, new Point(Padding.Left, Padding.Top));
```

---

If you don't want *any* extra code, the only way I know is using third-party libraries, e.g. [MahApps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro).

You can also create a custom behavior for the built-in `PasswordBox`, though it's not much simpler than a custom control.

Comment: Thanks man did it but man xaml is a pain in the a** sometimes